# How to modify the label of the power functions?

Tags: plotting

I have drawn the set of power function according to the following codes.

```
Plot[{x^(-1), x^0, Root[#^3 - x &, 1], x^(1/2), Root[#^3 - x^2 &, 1], 
  Root[#^8 - x^7 &, 2], x, x^2, x^3}, {x, -2, 5}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotLabels -> Automatic, Axes -> True, 
 AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}], AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
 ImageSize -> 500, PlotHighlighting -> "XSlice"]
```

the result is this:

[image]

How to modify the labels of functions to this as show in the following picture?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For plots with many possible functions, use a [`TogglerBar`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TogglerBar.html) to enable selectively showing or hiding the individual functions.

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

labels =
  {x^("-1"), x^"0", x^("1/3"), x^("1/2"), x^("2/3"), x^("7/8"), x, x^2, x^3} //
   ToRadicals;

funcs = labels /. str_String :> ToExpression[str];

colors = ColorData[97, "ColorList"];
```

Display

```
Manipulate[
 index = Sort@index;
 Plot[Evaluate@(Tooltip /@ funcs[[index]]), {x, -2, 5},
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 5}, {-5.1, 8.1}},
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05],
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  PlotStyle -> colors[[index]],
  PlotLabels -> labels[[index]],
  Axes -> True,
  AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}],
  AxesLabel -> {x, y},
  ImageSize -> 500,
  PlotHighlighting -> hilite],
 Row[{
   Control[{{index, Range@Length@funcs, "functions"},
     Thread[(Range@Length@funcs) -> labels],
     ControlType -> TogglerBar}],
   Spacer[20],
   Control[{{hilite, "XSlice", "HighLight"},
     {"XSlice", "YSlice", "XYDroplines", None}}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for providing the code! This is very practical. There are several issues: 1. The function x ^ (1/3) is an odd function, and there are images in the first and third quadrants, but after running the code, there are only images in the first quadrant. 

2. The function x ^ (2/3) is an even function, and there are images in both the first and second quadrants, but after running the code, there are only images in the first quadrant.

Comment: You have a misunderstanding of roots. `(-1)^(1/3) // N` is complex as is `(-1)^(2/3) // N`. You presumably want `CubeRoot[x]` instead of `x^(1/3)` (look at `Reduce[{x^(1/3) == CubeRoot[x], x \[Element] Reals}, x]`) and `(x^2)^(1/3)` instead of `x^(2/3)` (look at `Reduce[{x^(2/3) == (x^2)^(1/3), x \[Element] Reals}, x]`)

Answer (score 6):

Is the following sufficient?
If yes, then you want to have a look at [**`ToRadicals`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRadicals.html)

```
forplot = 
  ToRadicals[{x^(-1), x^0, Root[#^3 - x &, 1], x^(1/2), 
    Root[#^3 - x^2 &, 1], Root[#^8 - x^7 &, 2], x, x^2, x^3}];
```

and then

```
Plot[{forplot}, {x, -2, 5}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotLabels -> Automatic,
  Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}], 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

> [image: plot]

**Edit:** the command [`PlotHighlighting`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotHighlighting.html) is missing because I do not have `v13.3` but I don't think it is going to cause any conflicts.

Comment: (+1) Happy New Year, mate! Thanks for all the fun with the ten ways to code something. :-)

Comment: @E.Chan-López Happy new year! Best wishes and many 10-ways (and more) to code one thing :-)